# Android app shortcut notification

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, shortcut, intentfilter

I add shortcut to my app in Launcher like this.

```
public void create(String name, Bitmap bitmap, int appID) {
    final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bitmap);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, appID);

    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I want to get some notification when app opened by this shortcut and get some parameters from it (shortcut name and id). Tried with BroadcastReceiver, but it works only when shortcut is created. When i open app with this shortcut, BroadcastReceiver gives me nothing.

```
    BroadcastReceiver rec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "intent received");
            if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Shortcut ID: " + intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 0));
                Log.d(TAG, "Shortcut name: " + intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME));
            }
        }

    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    context.registerReceiver(rec, filter);
```

How to get notified about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get some notification when app opened by this shortcut

Your `SplashActivity` will be started. If you are using that activity for something else, and you want to distinguish the two, do not have your shortcut go to `SplashActivity`, but instead have it go to something else.

> When i open app with this shortcut, BroadcastReceiver gives me nothing.

Correct.

First, there is no requirement that a home screen pay any attention to your `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` request.

Second, there is no requirement that a home screen send any sort of broadcast when the user taps on that shortcut. All that is expected is that the home screen start the activity associated with that shortcut.

Comment: Actually, i want to use a couple of shortcuts to launch the same activity (don't worry, it's for internal use, not for google play). SplashActivity will deicide, what to start next, based on Shortcut id. Is it possible to do?

Comment: @AndreyRankov: You can try putting extras on `shortcutIntent`. I would not count on getting those in `SplashActivity`, but it may work in some cases.

Comment: no, it doesn't work for me. I changed filter, but BroadcastReceiver cannot detect shortcutIntent

Comment: @AndreyRankov: **There will be no broadcast**. `shortcutIntent` is not used with `sendBroadcast()`. It is used with `startActivity()`. In your case, it will start `SplashActivity`. *If* you put extras *on `shortcutIntent`*, those extras *may* be delivered to `SplashActivity`, where it can get to them via `getIntent()`. I would not count on this, but it may work with some home screens.

Comment: brilliant, it works! Please post this as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Different shortcut intents can set different actions, e.g. `android:action="android.intent.action.RUN"` vs. `android:action="android.intent.action.QUICK_CLOCK"`, and the Activity's `onCreate()` can switch on `getIntent().getAction()`.